# GNOME 3.20 on Ubuntu 16.04 through VNC on AWS

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to access my AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) through VNC using a GNOME3 GUI, but the GUI I get looks very old. What am I doing wrong?

I started with a fresh EC2 instance and installed GNOME3 like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install gnome gnome-shell
```

After the GNOME install finished, the tutorials I read said I would get a prompt to use a display manager LightDM or GDM. I didn't get such prompt after/during the installation process.

I then tried to force the GDM3 install:

sudo apt-get install gdm
And I installed a few other packages:

```
apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

Then I installed the VNC server like this:

```
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

And I setup the VNC server and editing the startup file

```
vncserver
sudo vim ~/.vnc/xstartup
```

My startup file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

And then I restart the VNC server:

```
vncserver -kill :1
vncserver -geometry 1600x900
```

So after all this, I login through TightVNC on Windows and this is what it looks like:
    [image: TightVNC desktop]

This is definitely not the nice GNOME3 interface. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like the Gmone3 interface as I remember it, though I can't see the desktop because of the file manager and terminal which are obscuring it. Is it just that you are used to a different desktop theme?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?